# Is it legal to reject WSDLs where namespaces differs only in file extension (the part after the last dot)?

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl

I have a complicated web application which uses many web services. I have to start using a new one. The WSDL of this new service defines a target namespace which is almost the same as a namespace used in an older WSDL. Only the part after the last dot differs.

The package names deduced by JAXB are the same for them, and the ObjectFactory generated from the second one overwrites the other.

For example, one wsdl has a target namespace "http://foo.com/a.b.c", another one has "http://foo.com/a.b.c_2". Then the java package name will be com.foo.a.b for both namespaces which is a kind of collision.

I checked the JAXB spec and found this ( https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxb-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxb-2_0-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1542978637_f7c18a1892b0ff022071acdab6259bdd ) :

> D.5.1 Mapping from a Namespace URI An XML namespace is represented by
>   a URI. Since XML Namespace will be mapped to a Java package, it is
>   necessary to specify a default mapping from a URI to a Java package
>   name. The URI format is described in [RFC2396]. The following steps
>   describe how to map a URI to a Java package name. The example URI,
>   http://www.acme.com/go/espeak.xsd, is used to illustrate each step.
>
> 1. Remove the scheme and ":" part from the beginning of the URI, if present. Since there is no formal syntax to identify the optional URI
>      scheme, restrict the schemes to be removed to case insensitive checks
>      for schemes “http” and “urn”.
>
>    //www.acme.com/go/espeak.xsd
> 2. Remove the trailing file type, one of .?? or .??? or .html.
>
>    //www.acme.com/go/espeak
>
>    ...

Probably there are workarounds for this on my side, but I would like to have the provider of the web services to "correct" the situation by using "proper" namespaces which are not differing in only the last part (file name extension in JAXB parlance?).

I am looking for arguments for "my case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Namespaces in XML 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) [§2.3 Comparing URI References](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NSNameComparison):

> URI references identifying namespaces are compared when determining whether a name belongs to a given namespace, and whether two names belong to the same namespace. [Definition: The two URIs are treated as strings, and they are identical if and only if the strings are identical, that is, if they are the same sequence of characters. ] The comparison is case-sensitive, and no %-escaping is done or undone.

If your namespaces "only differ in file extension", these are different namespaces. If your tools generate the same package for them, the problem is on your side, not on the side of the WSDL author.

So no, you do not have really good arguments for "your case", sorry.

The fix is trivial: simply config target package per namespace. See the following question, for instance:

> [CXF: How to change package of WSDL imported XML Schema using JAXB external binding file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722813/cxf-how-to-change-package-of-wsdl-imported-xml-schema-using-jaxb-external-bindi)